# How to consistently slice the first and last character of a string in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help with writing a loop that can slice through a string, taking away the first and last character. I understand that the slice [0:-1] can target those two positions, but I need a way for it to iterate through the whole string. Here is a little snippet into what the output would ideally look like:

Input (min for length is 3) :

`string = 'ABCDEFGHI'`

Output:

`['ABCDEFGHI', 'BCDEFGH', 'CDEFG']`

I would be grateful for any guidance/advice!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
>>> [string[i:len(string)-i] for i in range(3)]
['ABCDEFGHI', 'BCDEFGH', 'CDEFG']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function you can use:

```
def foo(string, limit=None):
    output = [string]
    i = 0
    if limit == None:
        while i < len(string) / 2 - 1:
            output.append(output[-1][1:-1])
            i += 1
    else:
        while i < limit - 1:
            output.append(output[-1][1:-1])
            i += 1
    return output
```

The second parameter can be used to set a limit to the length of the array. It is optional.